# Angular2 load configuration from backend on startup

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my Angular2 app, I'm trying to load configurations from backend on bootstrap using HTTP so that I can use the extracted data for creating angular services.

Whenever I try to read the HTTP response saved in my Config, I always get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined** error.

It appears like the HTTP request completes only when the whole bootstrap method finishes, whereas my code tries to extract the Observable response before it is retrieved.

How can I fix it to extract configuration from server and use it to create angular services on startup? (I want to create services inside providers with extracted data)

Please comment if there is any better way of extracting configuration from server on startup.

My **main.ts** looks like this:

```js
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ConfigurationService, Config])
    .catch(err => console.error(err)
);
```

**configuration.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    load() {
        return this.http.get('config/getConfig').map(response => response.json());
    }

}
```

**config.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class Config {

    public config;

    constructor(public configurationService: ConfigurationService) {
        configurationService.load().subscribe(
            config => this.config = config,
            error => console.error('Error: ' + error)
        );
    }

    get(key: any) {
        return this.config[key];
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(public myService: MyService) {
    }

}
```

**my.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService{

    private url;

    constructor(public config: Config) {
        this.url = config.get('url');
    }
}
```

Comment: as it is clear from the error see your `url` once again, that is undefined

Comment: A good tutorial https://gist.github.com/fernandohu/122e88c3bcd210bbe41c608c36306db9

Answer (score 12):

You could leverage the `APP_INITIALIZER` service to reload the configuration before application starts:

```js
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  {
     provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
     useFactory: (config:Config) => {
       return config.load();
     },
     dependency: [ Config ]
   }
]);
```

For this, you need to adapt a bit your `ConfigService` class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  load() { // <------
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.get(...).map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(config => {
          this.config = config;
          resolve();
        });
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to access directly properties on the configuration object within your application.

Comment: I have a very similar requirement and I followed your  technique above. However, I found that `load()` function is invoked before the `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts` but configuration data is loaded afterwards. What if I want the configurations to be loaded before `ngOnInit`?

Comment: +1 Please ignore my previous comment. Today when I cleaned node_modules folder and reinstalled all libraries, it started working in right order. You are the man @Thierry

Comment: I've created a plunkr with Angular 2.0 (Final). http://plnkr.co/edit/U5LUZ0rRDcuCNJ5MBGwC

Comment: BTW, why does load() returns a value, who gets this value and what for? for me it works perfectly without it.

Comment: A little bit late, but I also managed it with this line of code:             useFactory: (config:Config) => () => config.load(),

Comment: How to do it in Angular4?

Answer (score 10):

When using AoT compilation it throws an error because the factory is an anonymous function. What you need to do then is export a function for the factory

```js
export function ConfigLoader(configService: ConfigService) {
    return () => configService.load();
}
```

and the configuration for the app looks like this:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: ConfigLoader,
            deps: [ConfigService]
        }],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

reference https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10789

Answer (score -1):

This is a better way to write the load function

```js
public load() {
    let promise =this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
    promise.then(config =>  this.validation = config);
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: How is this any better?

Comment: How would this handle relative/absolute url path ?

Comment: The answer is from 2017, I don’t work with angularjs anymore. And I guess there is new versions of angularjs since then