# Angular2 : How to load JSON data before App init

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my Angular app, I want to load a JSON data before app init, which I store in a service and use it through out my application.

I used resolver for loading the data before app init as suggessted in [Angular2 load configuration from backend on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300116/angular2-load-configuration-from-backend-on-startup). But the solution threw error when I did ng serve or ng build.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 43:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/name/src/app/app.module.ts

Please let me know how this error can be resolved or if there is any other way to load data before app init.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from './backend.service';
import { BackendResolver } from './backend.resolver';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

providers: [
SearchService,
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (config:SearchService) => () => config.call(),
  deps: [SearchService],
  multi: true },
  BackendResolver,
  MyService
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**backend.service.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
jsonData;
constructor(
    private http: Http,
) { }

call() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.http.get('assets/appData.json').map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(jsonData => {
                this.jsonData = jsonData;
                resolve();
            });
    });
  }
}
```

**backend.resolver.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { SearchService } from './backend.service';

@Injectable()
export class BackendResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
  private searchService: SearchService
  ) {}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {
  return this.searchService.call();
 }
}
```

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    resources;
    constructor() { }
    public getData() {
        return this.resources;
    }

    public saveData(param) {
        this.resources = param;
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';
import { SearchService } from './backend.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  jsonData: any;
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private searchService: SearchService
    ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
      this.jsonData = this.searchService.jsonData;
      this.myService.saveData(this.jsonData);
    }
}
```

**footer.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MyService } from '../my.service';
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-footer',
        templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
    })
    export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
        contactUs: any;
        constructor(
            private myService: MyService
        ) { }
        ngOnInit() {
            this.contactUs=this.myService.getData().contactUs;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why can't you do this.searchService.call().then((jsonData)=>{ this.jsonData=jsonData })

Comment: There is one problem with this approach. Added the above callback in app.component.ts, this will wait for the post call result then the result can be stored in myService.
But, in footer we are calling myService.getData(), this gets called before the setData method() resulting in the error "cannot read property 'contactUs' of undefined"'

Comment: If you are talking about undefined error in HTML template, I suggest adding *ngIf="contactInfo" to whatever div you going to access your contactInfo

Answer (score 0):

this is an annoying problem... it is here:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (config:SearchService) => () => config.call(),
  deps: [SearchService],
  multi: true 
}
```

You can't use arrow syntax for a custom provider factory function.  change it to an explicit function like:

```
useFactory: function(config:SearchService) {
    return config.call();
}
```

Comment: Removed the arrow syntax and wrote function as suggested, still its throwing the same error.